# JPA - SQLException create record

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink

I have imported this entity classes from database (with **Netbeans** function - *Entity Classes from Database*).

Unfortunately i cannot make it work.

**IMS_MEASUREMENTS table**

```
INSTALLED_IMS_ID - NUMBER(9)
MEASUREMENT_IMS_ORD - NUMBER(9)
MEASUREMENT_TYPE_ID - NUMBER(9)
DEVICE_ID - NUMBER(9)
MEASUREMENT_TIME - TIMESTAMP(3)
MEASUREMENT_VALUE - NUMBER(9,2)
MEASUREMENT_MAX_VALUE - NUMBER(9,2)
MEASUREMENT_MIN_VALUE - NUMBER(9,2)
NOTES - VARCHAR(255 BYTE)
PREVIOUS_INFO - NUMBER(5)
LAST_UPDATE - TIMESTAMP(3)
MEASUREMENT_PRECISION - NUMBER(2)
LOCALIZATION_ID - NUMBER(9)
```

**Primary key** is (INSTALLED_IMS_ID, MEASUREMENT_IMS_ORD)

**ImsMeasurements.java**

```
@Entity
public class ImsMeasurements implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    protected ImsMeasurementsPK imsMeasurementsPK;

    @Column(name = "MEASUREMENT_TYPE_ID")
    private Integer measurementTypeId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "MEASUREMENT_TIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date measurementTime;
    @Column(name = "MEASUREMENT_VALUE")
    private BigDecimal measurementValue;
    @Column(name = "MEASUREMENT_MAX_VALUE")
    private BigDecimal measurementMaxValue;
    @Column(name = "MEASUREMENT_MIN_VALUE")
    private BigDecimal measurementMinValue;
    @Column(name = "NOTES")
    private String notes;
    @Column(name = "PREVIOUS_INFO")
    private Integer previousInfo;
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdate;
    @Column(name = "MEASUREMENT_PRECISION")
    private Short measurementPrecision;
    @Column(name = "LOCALIZATION_ID")
    private Integer localizationId;
    ....
    ....

    //constructors
    public ImsMeasurements() {
    }

    public ImsMeasurements(ImsMeasurementsPK imsMeasurementsPK) {
        this.imsMeasurementsPK = imsMeasurementsPK;
    }

    public ImsMeasurements(ImsMeasurementsPK imsMeasurementsPK, Date measurementTime) {
        this.imsMeasurementsPK = imsMeasurementsPK;
        this.measurementTime = measurementTime;
    }

    public ImsMeasurements(int installedImsId, int measurementImsOrd) {
        this.imsMeasurementsPK = new ImsMeasurementsPK(installedImsId, measurementImsOrd);
    }
}
```

**ImsMeasurementsPK.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class ImsMeasurementsPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "INSTALLED_IMS_ID")
    private int installedImsId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "MEASUREMENT_IMS_ORD")
    private int measurementImsOrd;
    ....

    //constructors
    public ImsMeasurementsPK() {
    }

    public ImsMeasurementsPK(int installedImsId, int measurementImsOrd) {
        this.installedImsId = installedImsId;
        this.measurementImsOrd = measurementImsOrd;
    }
}
```

Setting **measure**.

```
//setting measure primary key    
ImsMeasurements mis = new ImsMeasurements(new ImsMeasurementsPK(1, 1));
....
```

**Persist** it.

```
em.persist(mis);
```

I am finding this kind of **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column**

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Error Code: 1438
Call: INSERT INTO SICURFER.IMS_MEASUREMENTS (LAST_UPDATE, LOCALIZATION_ID, MEASUREMENT_MAX_VALUE, MEASUREMENT_MIN_VALUE, MEASUREMENT_PRECISION, MEASUREMENT_TIME, MEASUREMENT_TYPE_ID, MEASUREMENT_VALUE, NOTES, PREVIOUS_INFO, MEASUREMENT_IMS_ORD, INSTALLED_IMS_ID, DEVICE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [13 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.ansaldosts.sic.dao.ImsMeasurements[ imsMeasurementsPK=com.ansaldosts.sic.dao.ImsMeasurementsPK[ installedImsId=1, measurementImsOrd=1 ] ])
```

**JPA provider** -> EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913

Value that i try to insert:

```
mis.setMeasurementValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(110));
mis.setMeasurementTypeId(10);
String s = "2014-04-17 12:05:00";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.ITALY).parse(s);
mis.setMeasurementTime(date);
mis.setMeasurementPrecision(Short.MIN_VALUE);
mis.setMeasurementMinValue(BigDecimal.ZERO);
mis.setMeasurementMaxValue(BigDecimal.ZERO);
mis.setLocalizationId(Integer.valueOf(10));
mis.setDeviceId(2);
mis.setImsSystems(110);
```

Where is the problem, where i'm wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Francesco

Comment: There is one value in you object `ImsMeasurements`  that is longer then the specified column in your table

Comment: show me a possibile solution, thanks

Comment: Can you find out what the [13 parameters bound] are? Add the values and the ddl.

Comment: I think that the problem are on the mapping from bin ImsMeasurementsPK to the primary composite key on the DB, but i don't understand the reason. The mapping are auto-generated from JPA using the Netbeans function ("Create entity from Classes").

Comment: I do not know Netbeans so I can not help you there.

Answer (score 2):

There are three fields use type 'BigDecimal' which may grow larger. You need check every column's type in db.

Comment: Thank you! I edit the question in way you can observe the DB data type and relative type generated from JPA automatically. Anything strange? Some inconsistency?

Comment: It seems the MEASUREMENT_PRECISION - NUMBER(2) has problem. It's length is only 2, but you have set a value with Short.MIN_VALUE which is -32768, its length is 5.